# How to handle the package version requirement, when two or more packages are depends on another common library?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-packaging

I am currently working on image detection project. I am using the bbox python library for detection.

During code execution I got the error: `**"ERROR: numba 0.55.1 has requirement numpy<1.22,>=1.18, but you'll have numpy 1.22.2 which is incompatible."**`

I tried: `"pip3 install numpy==1.21"` and it works for the numba package but the later code gets the error.

Because, my other packages are working with `numpy=1.22.2` version and lower than `1.22.0` generates error with other package dependencies.

So, how can to handle it?

Thank you for your valuable time. Appreciate in advance.

Comment: You could try upgrading your numba version or downgrading the other package until the requirements match

Comment: @JanWilamowski Numba currently doesn't support numpy>=1.22: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7754 . The way to tackle this is to find the latest version of the other dependencies that don't depend on numpy 1.22 features. If that is impossible (or undesirable) the next best thing is to install numba alongside numpy 1.21,  to then upgrade numpy to 1.22, to install the other packages, and to hope not to run into any known numba incompatibility (might have to downgrade pip to dodge dependency resolution). The third option is to not use numba, but that isn't always possible.

Comment: You could try using conda instead. Specify the package names without versions and it will try to figure out a compatible setup. It may still fail though.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install numpy==1.23.5
```

this worked for me, try this

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.